# Trouble Generating MD5 Fingerprint for Google Maps API key

Tags: md5, fingerprint

I have a problem. When I open command prompt this is already entered C:\Documents and Settings\Chris>

In my Java program file, there are 3 java folders, i.e jdk1.6.0_13, jdk1.6.0_18 and jdk1.6.0_23...I figured the last two must be updates. this is what I entered on the Command Prompt.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Chris.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

After hitting 'Enter', the awful message that says "....is not recognized an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' appeared. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command to get your MD5 fingerprint.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey
         -keystore "Your debug key location" -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can also get a full tutorial at http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2011/12/show-google-map-on-your-android-app.html